# Auto batch replace smart object in multiple files Photoshop Cs6

Tags: adobe-photoshop, smartobject

Have another question.  I have a project that I'm working.
I have a psd layered template with a smart object.  The goal is to change the image in the document and replace the current smart object with a new image.  However I have hundreds that need to be done so I'm trying to figure out away to do it automatically.

The goal would be for me to select a folder where the files are located and then run it as a "Script" from with in photoshop.  I tried to do it and I couldn't figure out how to get an action correctly.

Can anyone help?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are referring to is data driven graphics or variable graphics generating. Here is a decent tutorial that walks through the details. [Data-Driven Graphics Guide](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i9Ms34nYRFI).

Comment: You're awesome, this is exactly what I want.